# Dont work datepicker from gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Version Rails 5 beta 3. I am using gem jquery-ui-rails 5.0.5

**gemfile**

```
................................................
      gem 'jquery-rails'      
      # Use SCSS for stylesheets
      gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
      # Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
      # Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
      gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

**application.js:**

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/datepicker
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require cocoon
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
```

**application.css**

```
/**
 * application.css
 *
 *= require jquery-ui/datepicker
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree ./all
```

**freelancers/edit.html.erb**

```
<li class="form-fields__group form-fields__group_birthdate">
        <label for="freelancer_birth_date">Birthday</label>
        <div class= "field">
          <%= f.text_field :birthday %>
        </div>
      </li>
```

Table name: freelancers

```
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  first_name     :string
#  last_name      :string
#  rate           :integer
#  birthday       :date
```

**javascripts/freelancer.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  $('#freelancer_birthday').datepicker()
```

I click on field birthday, but dont open datepicker. Nothing happens. How can solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Try putting the date picker after jquery_ujs in application.js and don't forget to restart your server.

Comment: i tryed, dont work